# What is the value of $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!}$

Tags: limits, summation, continuity

I'm having some conceptual difficulty with the sum:

$$\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!}$$

It was claimed in an online source that this sum diverged to infinity, but no justification was given.

I'm having trouble seeing why this would be true. I understand that, through comparison with the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n$, one can conclude it diverges for $|r| \ge 1$, and converges for $|r|<1$.

However, the limit is throwing me off. This sum should not be uniformly convergent on (-1, 1), so I see no reason why one should be able to bring the limit inside the sum. Moreover, it would seem to me that:
$$\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!} \text{ converges }$$
$$\lim_{r \to 1^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!} = \infty$$
$$\lim_{r \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!} \space\space \text{ does not exist}$$

Comment: This is the particular thread on MathStack I am referring to if anyone is curious about the context:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610862/solution-verification-the-series-sum-zn-has-the-unit-circle-as-a-natura

Comment: Each term is increasing as you take the limit, and they each go to one. Since there are infinitly many terms the sum therefore becomes arbitrarily large in the limit.

Comment: $f_N(r) = \frac{1}{1+\sum_{n=1}^N r^{n!}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$

Comment: @infinitylord For any $r>0$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!} > r^{1!} = r$, so how could it converge to $0$ as $r\to 1^{-}$?

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, that was a dumb little error, I more meant to say "converges"

Comment: @Vik78: I see what you're saying, but isn't that essentially the same thing as bringing the limit inside the sum?

Comment: @infinitylord Regarding interchanging sum and limits: since all terms are positive this is a perfectly valid approach to get a lower bound (which is all you need to prove divergence).

Comment: No, it's not. Let $k > 0$ be an integer. Given $\epsilon > 0$, you can choose $\delta > 0$ so that for all $r$ with $|1-r| < \delta$, $1-\epsilon < r^{n!}$ for all $1 \le n \le k$. All the other terms are positive, so whenever $|1-r| < \delta$ the sum is at least $k*(1-\epsilon)$. Since $k$ and $\epsilon$ were arbitrary the sum diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

For $N\in\Bbb N$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!}>\sum_{n=1}^N r^{n!}>\frac{N}2$$
for values of $r$ in a suitable interval $(1-\epsilon_N,1)$.
Thus $\liminf_{r\to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n!}\ge N/2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{k=1}^nr^{k!}=n
$$