# Boundary limit of a typical holomorphic function with natural boundary being the unit circle

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, power-series

The power series $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1}z^{n!}$ defines a holomorphic function on the unit disk $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. It has the unit circle as the natural boundary, see [(solution verification) the series $\sum z^{n!}$ has the unit circle as a natural boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610862/solution-verification-the-series-sum-zn-has-the-unit-circle-as-a-natura).

The question is: Does the limit $\lim_{x\in(0,1),x\to 1^-}(1-x)f(x)$ exist?

The relation between singular boundary points and boundary values can be subtle. For example, $g(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1}z^{2^n}/n^2$ defines a continuous function on $\bar{D}$, which is holomorphic in $D$ and also has natural boundary the unit circle (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/273332/153360).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $m \ge 2$, we have $\log (1-1/m) \le -\frac{1}{2m}$ so $(1-1/m)^{k!} \le e^{-k!/(2m)}$ which means that $\sum_{k, k! \ge 2m^2} (1-1/m)^{k!} \le 2 e^{-m}$ by trivial majorization since if $k_0$ is the first integer st $k_0! \ge 2m^2$ we have $$(k_0+r)!-2m^2 \ge (k_0+r)!-k_0! \ge rk_0! \ge 2rm^2$$ so  $e^{-(k_0+r)!/(2m)} \le e^{-m}e^{-rm}$ and $\sum_{r \ge 0}e^{-rm} \le 2$

But since for $k$ large enough we have by Stirling that $k! \ge (k/e)^{k}$, it follows that $k! \le 2m^2$ means that $k \log (k/e) \le 2 \log m +\log 2$ so $k \le \log m$ if $m$ large enough as $\frac{\log m \log ((\log m)/e)}{2\log m+\log 2} \to \infty, m \to \infty$

Hence for large enough $m$ it means that there are at most $\log m$ terms in the sum $\sum z^{k!}$ for which $k! < 2m^2$ hence majorizing those trivially by $1$ we have that for $x=1-1/m$ $$(1-x)\sum_{k \ge 1}x^{k!} \le \frac{\log m + 2e^{-m}}{m}$$

Picking now $1/m \le x < 1/(m+1)$ clearly we can apply similar estimates (the number of trivially estimated terms is at most $\log (m+1)$ and the denominator is at least $m$) and get that

$$(1-x)\sum_{k \ge 1}x^{k!} \le \frac{\log (m+1) + 2e^{-m}}{m}$$

for $x$ close enough to $1$ so $m$ large enough, hence the limit exists and is $0$

Answer (score 3):

The result can be generalized substantially. Namely, let $a_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-1/k}<\infty$ for a fixed natural number $k.$  Then
$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{a_n}=0\qquad (*)$$
Clearly the assumptions are satisfied for $a_n=n!$ and any $k.$

The proof goes as follows.
Consider the function $[0,1]\ni x\mapsto (1-x)^{1/k}x^a,$ for $a>0.$ The maximal value is attained at $x={ka\over ka+1}$ and is equal to $$\left ({ka\over ka+1}\right) ^{a}{1\over (ka+1)^{1/k}}\le {1\over a^{1/k}}$$
For a fixed $N$ we have
$$(1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{a_n}=(1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{a_n}+ \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty (1-x)^{1/k}x^{a_n}\\
\le (1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{a_n}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n^{-1/k}$$
Hence
$$\limsup_{x\to 1^-}(1-x)^{1/k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{a_n}\le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  a_n^{-1/k}$$
Since $N$ is arbitrary we get
$(*).$